# How to get test environment at run time

Tags: testing, go

I want to check if codes are running for the `go test`,so that I could make some configurations.

Is there any function to do that?
Like:

runtime.IsBeingTested()

Comment: I wouldn't consider a test authoritative if the tested code needs to know if it is being tested (and hence run differently). The test will not test code paths that would get executed if it were told that it is not being tested. All the code that needs to know if a test is being executed should be in the `XX_test.go` files.

Comment: If you want different configs in tests why not just setup at the beginning of the test function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just specify that you run a test in test's `init`. For example, in pkg.go:

```
package pkg

var isTesting = false

// ...
```

And in pkg_test.go:

```
package pkg

func init() {
    isTesting = true
}

// ...
```

This technique can be used not just with `bool`s but with any data or function. If you have some variable in your package (in your case, a configuration variable), you can just override it in `init`.

Comment: But does it means that one needs to include this code in all the test code?

Comment: @songyy I don't understand what you mean. This is only done once per package.

Comment: suppose we have 2 files needs to check the `isTesting` property. Then in each of the 2 files, we'll need to define the `isTesting` variable is it..?

Comment: @songyy Again, if those files are in the same package, then no. This is done once per package.