# setting a variable from test file in golang

Tags: go

i'm trying to set a variable from my unit tests file

main_test.go

```
var testingMode bool = true
```

main.go

```
if testingMode == true {
  //use test database
} else {
  //use regular database
}
```

If I run "go test", this works fine. If I do "go build", golang complains that testingMode is not defined (which should be the case since tests aren't part of the program).

But it seems if I set the global variable in main.go, I'm unable to set it in main_test.

What's the correct way to about this?

Comment: Where in your `main_test.go` are you defining the variable? Keep in mind that your `init()` function is executed at startup, but `main()` isn't.

Comment: im defining it outside of any function in my test file

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Go,how to get test environment at run time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476307/in-go-how-to-get-test-environment-at-run-time)

Comment: BTW, this is a bad way to handle test stubbing. The standard way would be to have the relevant code use an interface (or in this case perhaps a `*sql.DB` variable) that the test code can replace with a mock implementation (or a in memory `*sql.DB`).

Comment: interesting. can you point to a link with more information about this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

Define your variable as global in `main.go`:

```
var testingMode bool
```

And then set it to be `true` in your test file `main_test.go`:

```
func init() {
    testingMode = true
}
```

Comment: i want test to be false when executed regularly, i only want testing to be true when I run "go test"

Comment: With this new example, `testingMode` will be false by default (golang zero value), and set to `true` by the `main_test.go` init function.

Answer (score 1):

Pierre Prinetti's Answer doesn't work in 2019.

Instead, do this. It's less then ideal, but gets the job done

```
//In the module that you are testing (not your test module:
func init() {
    if len(os.Args) > 1 && os.Args[1][:5] == "-test" {
        log.Println("testing")//special test setup goes goes here
        return // ...or just skip the setup entirely
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to overwrite a variable for one specific unit-test ?

Comment: Is there any other cleaner way doing this?