# Unit Testing tls.LoadX509KeyPair fails if no certs provided

Tags: go, tls1.2

```
cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(os.Getenv("CERT"), os.Getenv("KEY"))
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

I want to write a unit test for a function that contains this snippet of code. However, my test environment will never have any content in `os.Getenv("CERT")`/`os.Getenv("KEY")`. This makes the code(`tls.LoadX509KeyPair()`) return an error, which doesn't let me test the function.
How should I go about mocking/modifying this snippet?

Comment: Refactor. If the code under test relies on an environment that isn't reproduced under test, either you can't test it or you have to refactor it.

Comment: You mean using os.Getenv() in go code is a bad practice?

Comment: No, there's nothing wrong with it. I mean the broader sense of "environment" - the environment variables, local files (e.g. certificates), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works by defining vars for the `certFile` and `keyFile` and then overriding them in the test environment.

```
//.. 
var certFile = os.Getenv("CERT")
var keyFile = os.Getenv("KEY")
//...
cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(certFile, keyFile)
  if err != nil {
     return err
  }
```

Follow the below link to see how to override the vars in a test env.
[In Go,how to get test environment at run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476307/in-go-how-to-get-test-environment-at-run-time)